# How to map a network drive with winget configuration file

Tags: powershell, configuration, winget

I'm writing a winget configuration file ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/configuration/create#where-to-find-powershell-dsc-resource-modules)) with a lot of actions (Install apps, set env var, set registry, set pc configuration, clone repos, ...). I found no easy way to map a network drive.

I try to set registry keys ([Link](https://superuser.com/questions/885754/where-does-windows-store-network-drive-mappings)) and this is working (after pc restart).

```
# yaml-language-server: $schema=https://aka.ms/configuration-dsc-schema/0.2

properties:
  configurationVersion: 0.2.0
  resources:
    - resource: PSDscResources/Registry
      directives:
        description: Map network drive H
      settings:
        Key: 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\H'
        Ensure: Present
        ValueName: RemotePath
        ValueType: String
        ValueData: \\my_network_path
        Force: True
    - resource: PSDscResources/Registry
      directives:
        description: Map network drive H
      settings:
        Key: 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\H'
        Ensure: Present
        ValueName: ConnectFlags
        ValueType: DWord 
        ValueData: 0
```

But isn't there an easier way to map a network drive by a winget configuration file? I have not been able to execute the powershell command New-PsDrive directly in the configuration file (is that even possible?) and have not found a suitable dsc resource package.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution to use the DscResource [Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/reference/psdscresources/resources/script/script?view=dsc-2.0):

```
properties:
  configurationVersion: 0.2.0
  resources:
    - resource: PSDscResources/Script
      directives:
        description: Run script
      settings:
        GetScript: {}
        SetScript: |
          New-PSDrive -Name "N" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\ner91a0002.niehl.ford.com\eese_eu\hil" -Persist -Scope Global
        TestScript: |
          Test-Path N:
```

Is there any better solution?